# Read dynamic variables from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I am reading a property called `clients` from application.properties, for example:

```
clients=FI,S4
```

However, now I also want to read additional properties, where the name depends on the values of the `clients` property, for example:

```
clients=FI,S4
marchentId.FI=12321321
marchentId.S4=11111111
```

How can I read these properties depending on the value of the `clients` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take reference from this code snippet

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
public class Properties {

 @Autowired
 private Environment env;

 @Value("${clients}")
 private String[] clients;

 public List getClients(){
  return Arrays.asList(clients);
 }

// put single client Id to get corresponds merchant 
 public String getMarchentIdValue(String key)
 {
  String returnValue = "No value";

  String keyValue = env.getProperty(key);

  if( keyValue!= null && !keyValue.isEmpty())
  {
   returnValue = keyValue;
  }
  return returnValue;
 }
}
```